# Simple calling unserialize() function adds line break into output buffer - wtf?

Tags: php, serialization, kohana

I am writing the payment gateway, and need throw xml-response to payment server. But, suddenly, my XML was corrupted by line break in beginning of the generated document.

I use the Kohana 3 framework, and it uses the PHP function `unserialize()` to retrieve the session object, and newline prints to output buffer when this function is called.
This code:

```
<?php
echo 123;
$object = unserialize($data);
document_creation_and_outputting;
```

returns result like this:

```
123
document_body
```

But this code:

```
<?php
$object = unserialize($data);
echo 123;
document_creation_and_outputting;
```

returns document like this:

```
(empty line)
123document_body
```

So you can see, if the generated doc_body doesn't have a line break, my script doesn't have line break at first line (because we don't see a line break before "123" in the first example), and, I promise, I use UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM.

So my question is: what's going on?

---

I used `ob_end_clean()` to clean the buffer before outputting generated document, and it solved my problem, but I really don't understand `unserialize()`'s behavior.

Comment: The problem is not the call to unserialize() but that any of the php files that you include to make the call has some (maybe invisible) whitespace at the beginning before the <?php or at the end after the ?>. Check the beginnings and endings of the files you include.

Comment: The only way I can think of `unserialize` doing this is if it decodes an object with a `__wakeup` method that outputs a newline. More-likely the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: In case the linebreak is the very first output of the script you could use [`headers_sent($file, $line);`](http://docs.php.net/headers_sent) and then check $file/$line to (hopefully) see what produced this output.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Or if deserialization triggers a class to be loaded from a file containing a leading/trailing newline

Comment: @NineBerry, look at example, in both cases i include the same files, and insert my echo "123"; DIRECTLY before, and DIRECTLY after unserialize function. Besides, if i just comment line with unserialize(), whitespace vanishes. Besides, i dont use ?> in scripts. Only in templates, and i check them.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara i don't use __wakeup() methods. I have not them in my scripts.

Comment: @VolkerK it's don't show nothing uncommon. headers sent where they must be.

Comment: @duskwuff I checked it, and, for my pain, those class files don't have newlines.

Comment: When you use `headers_sent($file, $line)`in the case when the empty line appears as the start of the output, then the parameters $file and $line should tell you where the empty line was written to the output.

Comment: This is guesswork as long as you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moron.
unserialize() received this:
[My fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14E6h.png)

Sorry, guys. I just fuNcked up.

Comment: @duskwuff - you was right in this: Or if deserialization triggers a class to be loaded from a file containing a leading/trailing newline